# move the names of the columns to x-axis with vegalite and observable

Tags: observable, bar-chart, orientation, vega-lite

I am using VegaLite and working in Observable notebook. I need to swap the labels for the column up top and x-axis, so that I have the status on top and the names on the bottom x-axis.

```
vegalite({
  width: 50,
  data: { values: StackVega },
  mark: 'bar',
  encoding: {
    column: {
      field: "new_name",
      type: "nominal",
      spacing: 2,
      title: "Name",
    // axis: {orient: "bottom"}
    },
    y: {
      type: "quantitative",
      aggregate: "sum",
      field: "new_rate",
      title: "Rate",
      axis: { grid: false }
    },
    x: { type: "nominal", field: "stat", axis: { title: "" } },
    color: {
      type: "nominal",
      field: "stat",
      scale: { range: ["#675193", "#ca8861"] }
    }
  },
  config: {
    view: { stroke: "transparent" },
    axis: { domainWidth: 1 }
  }
})
```

I have tried to add `axis: {orient: "bottom"}` but that didn't work and if I swap the fields with column and x it breaks the chart.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column labels are not controlled by `axis`, they are controlled by `header`. Use `header: {"labelOrient": "bottom"}`. See [Header](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/header.html) for more information.

Comment: ```  "encoding": {
    "column": {
      "field": "age",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "header": {"labelOrient": "bottom"}
    },``` doesn't move the names to the x-axis but shifts it lower so that they collapse with the bars themselves... Was the code you provided supposed to move the names to x-axis?

Comment: If that doesn't move the labels to the bottom, it is a bug and would be worth reporting to the vega-lite issue tracker.

Comment: It looks like this was recently fixed: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/7150

Comment: I saw that it was "fixed", however, the code still doesn't work for me. I have `"header": {"labelOrient": "bottom"} },` and that doesn't move the labels still. I am not sure if this could be Observable bug or vega lite, but this just doesn't work :/ They mentioned that it can work if you specify it in config, which I also tried, and nothing.

Comment: It was fixed three days ago, and the fix has not yet made it into a release. To use the fixed code, you can either wait for a new release, or build the library yourself from the master branch.